# How to destructure and derefence tuple in rust

Tags: rust, reference, destructuring

Is there a way to simplify the below code by dereferencing `foo` and `bar` on the same line as we destructure the tuple?

```rs
let a = "a";
let b = "b";
let c = (&a, &b);

// Can we dereference here?
let (foo, bar) = c;

let foo_loc = *foo;
let bar_loc = *bar;
println!("{}", foo_loc);
println!("{}", bar_loc);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **pattern match** the references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = "a";
    let b = "b";
    let c = (&a, &b);
    let (&foo, &bar) = c;
    println!("{}", foo);
    println!("{}", bar);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d76ee4563b06cf4ae87ced34305c5e8e)

Comment: Rust newbie here; wondering would it be the same/similar if we would do `let (foo, bar) = c.to_owned();` ?

Comment: @heemayl yes and no, you are already doing `to_owned` when moving `c`. So you would still need to pattern match in order to solve what he asked.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: `c.to_owned()` would call the `ToOwned` implementation for `(&&str, &&str)`, which is covered by the blanket implementation `impl<T> ToOwned for T where T: Clone` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#impl-ToOwned-5. Therefore, `c.to_owned()` will simply return a clone of `c` and thus does not influence the structure of the value.